# Unable to post a request via postman ERROR: Algorithm not supported

Tags: postman

Sending post request through Postman with some params and getting error

```
"message": "Algorithm not supported"
```

Please advise if someone knows why this error is coming.

I am expecting the reason behind the error and the steps to remove this error.

Comment: Post your request here . need more details to understand

Comment: url : localhost:8000/facebook/login , code : AQCNoWT3yhvCFz6LvvPF3nWriEjOK1VdhS1Ou0VN4Z8pgmE0lvOILWIVCOm , redirect": "https://mobile.com/"

Comment: What are the params for which you are getting algorithm not supported ?

Comment: Are you sure your backend is not responding with the algorithm not supported status ?

Comment: yes i have tried sending post request many times and back end is not responding

Comment: urls works the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.